# How can I convert the dates in milliseconds in classical date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

Hello I am using python and I need to convert my date because this in my array of dates:

I precise the name of my variable is `df['time']`.

```
1    737214.791667
2    737214.833333
3    737214.875000
4    737214.916667
Name: time, Length: 500, dtype: float64
```

Basically the problem is all is in milliseconds and I need to have classical date with days.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (pandas 0.24.2) the command

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms')
```

works fine. You can also try:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'].mul(1e6).astype(np.int64))
```

Comment: Actually if I put add this line below your line : `df['time'] = df['time'].apply(mdates.date2num)` it works but I get milliseconds and not days I mean not a classical date